# Вывести на экран целую часть и остаток при делении двух целых чисел

Tags: java

Как вывести целое число с остатком при делении?

Я пробовала так: `double fartheist = 9 % 5;`, в этом случае выводит `4.0`

Я пробовала и так: `double fartheist = 9 / 5;`, выводит  `1.0`

я и меняла тип данных на `float`, но все равно не помогло.

Как мне вывести `1,8`?

Answer (score 1):

это прив**е**дение типов называется))

public class tt {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int q1 = 9;
        int q2 = 5;
        double d = (double)q1/q2;
        System.out.println(d);
    }

}
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо

Comment: силь ву пле ) )

Answer (score 0):

Если с числами работать, то можно сделать так.

```
double a = 9.0 / 5;
```

Т.е. добавляя .0 к числу ты делаешь его как раз таки double и ответ приводится к double